# How to save a html file as a pdf using command line in windows OS?

Tags: command-line, pdf

Hi I would like to convert an html file into a pdf using  the command prompt .

I tried 
**copy abc.html abc.pdf** (Did not work)

Please give me some suggestion as to how to do it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just copy from one format to another.  With PDF, the easiest way is to print to PDF.  Applications like CutePDF or TotalPDFConverter will do that.

http://www.coolutils.com/CommandLine/TotalPDFConverter

http://www.cutepdf.com/support/faq.asp

Comment: thanks Ed , Im not able to find out  the license agreement for cutepdf is that GNU ?

Comment: Yes.  It's the GNU license.  http://www.cutepdf.com/products/CutePDF/writer.asp

Answer (score 0):

I've used `wkhtmltopdf` to a good degree of success.

Chromium derived browsers are able to do this now in headless mode, but in my experience wkhtmltopdf seems to do this with much less overhead.

https://wkhtmltopdf.org/